# How do I retrieve the information about the maximum and minimum price of a stock just during the after hours, or the pre-market?

Tags: google-sheets, stock, google-finance, stockquotes

How do I retrieve the information about the maximum  and minimum price of a stock just during the after hours, or the pre-market? For example, I can use the formula =GOOGLEFINANCE("TSLA";"high";"02/02/2022") which will retrieve the maximum price of the stock during regular hours. However, I can't find a way to get the maximum price just during after hours and premarket hours, excluding regular hours. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

not supported via GOOGLEFINANCE formula. for max, you can do `high` for min its `low` and then you can do only `close`

[image]

for `after hours` and `pre-market` you will need to resort to scrapping some non-javascript website that holds this data

Comment: Even I posted a query here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762350/google-finance-does-not-show-last-closing-price-after-market-hours-it-just-show) and tried lot of things but could not get after market close price. I am still trying to fetch the figures but not sure if the site I mentioned in my question is javascript or non-javascript.